# How to show the dataGrid from a text search filter with c# in postgresql

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a text button that should filter the name of a person from a data table. the code is:

```
private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataView DT = new DataView(dataTable);
            DT.RowFilter = string.Format("nome_docente LIKE '%{0}%'", txtSearch.Text);
            dgvTabela.DataSource = DT;
        }
```

When running the code after the table loads, when I search for a name all the table disappears, and nothing is shown.
Can someone give me a tip on this?

Best regards

Comment: `dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = null; dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $"nome_docente LIKE '%{txtSearch.Text}%'"`. Do evaluate if the TextChanged event is actually what you want. You can also handle `Keys.Enter` and filter your DataTable when an User presses `Enter`. You didn't specify whether you already have other active filters.

Comment: Hi @Jimi, it is not working. It gives an error in the first line dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = null; Yes, I have another filter but it is in a combo box.

Comment: Set it to `string.Empty` then.

Comment: Hi @Jimi, thank you so much, it's working :)